# whats wrong with mysql tigger

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the trigger im trying to add. I keep getting "Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS leaderboard.badges_AUPD$$
USE leaderboard$$
CREATE TRIGGER `badges_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `badges` FOR EACH ROW

set new.badgelevel := case when badgepercent < 50 then 0
                    when badgepercent < 75 then 1
                    else 2 end;
    $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need an `end` at the end of the `case` (`else 2 end`).  This seems like a simple typographical error, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  iv edited my post . do you mean like that

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger should be `before update` since after update you cant set any column of the same table, and also missing the `begin` part

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS leaderboard.badges_AUPD$$
USE leaderboard$$
CREATE TRIGGER `badges_AUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON `badges` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if new.badgepercent < 50 then
   set new.badgelevel = 0 ;
 elseif new.badgepercent < 75 then
   set new.badgelevel = 1 ;
 else 
   set new.badgelevel = 2;
 end if;

end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set new.badgelevel = 1 ;
else 
   set set new.badgelevel = 2;
end if;

en' at line 7

Comment: Ouch I had added `set` 2 times fixed it now.

Comment: does the trigger run automatically ?

Comment: It will run the moment you update anything into the table `badges`

Comment: Ok Thanks . It didnt work the first time i updated the table , but seems to be working now